# CMake failing to tell MSVC to use C++11?

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, cmake, visual-studio-2019

I'm using CMake to generate the build system of a library of mine. I have some example programs, while I build with the language standard set to C++11:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF)
```

Now, for a Windows build, I (or rather GitHub) is using MSVC 16 on Windows 10. For this program:

```
add_executable(bandwidthtest modified_cuda_samples/bandwidthtest/bandwidthtest.cpp)
```

I get this compilation command generated by CMake (I think it's CMake 3.26.3; lines broken for readability):

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\HostX64\x64\CL.exe
/c /I"D:\a\cuda-api-wrappers\cuda-api-wrappers\src"
/I"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.7\include" /nologo /W4 
/WX- /diagnostics:column /O2 /Ob2 /D _MBCS /D WIN32 /D _WINDOWS /D NDEBUG 
/D _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS 
/D _SILENCE_EXPERIMENTAL_FILESYSTEM_DEPRECATION_WARNING /D "CMAKE_INTDIR=\"Release\"" 
/Gm- /EHsc /MD /GS /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Zc:inline /Fo"bandwidthtest.dir\Release\\" /Fd"bandwidthtest.dir\Release\vc142.pdb" /external:W0 
/Gd /TP /errorReport:queue  
/external:I "C:/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v11.7/include" /Zc:__cplusplus 
"D:\a\cuda-api-wrappers\cuda-api-wrappers\examples\modified_cuda_samples\bandwidthtest\bandwidthtest.cpp"
```

So, this doesn't have an `/std` option. It does have `/Zc:__cplusplus`, but I added that one myself (I think CMake should have added it as well, but that's a [known open issue](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/18837)).

Given that MSVC does not default to using C++11 as the language standard (to the best of my recollection) - why does CMake not add `/std:c++11`? And if it's because of some configuration problem - why doesn't it say there's a problem?

Note: This is *not* a question about Visual Studio, the question is about CMake's behavior.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like MSVC doesn't officially support C++11. [This page about the `/std` switch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/std-specify-language-standard-version?view=msvc-160) shows us it can take: `/std:c++14`, `/std:c++17`, `/std:c++20`, and C-language values (as of the time of writing). But no `/std:c++11` :-(

This does not fully answer the question though. CMake should have dealt with this differently, and the fact that it doesn't [is a bug](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/24836), IMNSHO.

Comment: Not to forget `/std:c++latest`.

Comment: I believe c++14 is the minimum for the compiler from 2015 to present.

Comment: @AlexReinking: Anyway, [files this](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/24836).

Comment: "This does not fully answer the question though." - Eh? The question in the question post is "Why does CMake not add `/std:c++11`?" And the first paragraph of your answer fully answers this question: there is no such option in MSVC. If you intended to ask "why CMake does **not emit an error** because required C++11 is not supported by the compiler", then it is better to write that directly in the question post. (But now such change would invalidate [273K's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76067830/3440745)..)

Comment: @Tsyvarev: It's implied that either MSVC will act as i requested, or CMake should complain. But - I'll edit to clarify

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Visual Studio 2019 does not support C++11: [/std (Specify Language Standard Version)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/std-specify-language-standard-version?view=msvc-160) is missing `/std:c++11`.

> The Microsoft C++ compiler in Visual Studio 2017 and later versions doesn't support C++ standards modes earlier than C++14 (`/std:c++14`).

Comment: Umm, I already gave an answer saying just that.

Comment: You answered with a wrong link.

Comment: So you could make a comment saying the link should point to the 160, not 170, page.